# После удаления программы не освободилось место на жёстком диске

Tags: macos, mac, apple, ssd

Был установлен *bootcamp*, после чего попытался его удалить через ассистент, и что-то пошло не так. Он вроде как удалился, но место на диске всё равно занимает. Отформатировать или объединить диск через загрузочную флешку с ОС не удалось.

Пытался загрузить с *recovery* образа OS X Lion, который лежит на сайте Apple. Однако при его загрузке был показан крест на весь экран.

1. Вывод дисковой утилиты:

   > **Применение изменений к «APPLE SSD SD0128F Media»**
   >
   > Сбой операции...
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Проверка многосвязных файлов.
   >   Проверка расширенных атрибутов.
   >   Проверка информации тома.
   >   Проверка информации тома.
   >   Неверный номер свободного блока тома
   >   Код ответа файловой системы: 8.
   >   Сбой проверки или восстановления файловой системы.
   >   Сбой операции...
2. Вывод `diskutil`:

   > `MacBook-Air-Mod:~ newuser$ diskutil cs list`
   >
   > ```
   > CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
   > |
   > +-- Logical Volume Group D582022C-561D-4203-A7B8-FC710D5E6C52
   >     =========================================================
   >     Name:         Macintosh HS
   >     Status:       Online
   >     Size:         75364974592 B (75.4 GB)
   >     Free Space:   1716224 B (1.7 MB)
   >     |
   >     +-< Physical Volume CF16733B-0DCE-4EFC-B1E6-5704EA73FC94
   >     |   ----------------------------------------------------
   >     |   Index:    0
   >     |   Disk:     disk0s2
   >     |   Status:   Online
   >     |   Size:     75364974592 B (75.4 GB)
   >     |
   >     +-> Logical Volume Family 11F71D40-93CE-4079-A5BB-5FF202A8392D
   >         ----------------------------------------------------------
   >         Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
   >         Encryption Status:       Unlocked
   >         Conversion Status:       Complete
   >         High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
   >         |                        Passphrase Required
   >         |                        Accepts New Users
   >         |                        Has Visible Users
   >         |                        Has Volume Key
   >         |
   >         +-> Logical Volume 41AC58F3-36B5-4A1E-8783-3F919B61DDBD
   >             ---------------------------------------------------
   >             Disc:                  disc1
   >             Status:                Online
   >             Size (Total):          75010932736 B (75.0 GB)
   >             Revertible:            No
   >             Revert status:         Reboot required
   >             LV Name:               Macintosh HD
   >             Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
   >             Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
   > ```

Как вернуть «потерянное» место?